# Why Asp.net Web Service(asmx) not fire?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I am calling web service with Asp.net using jquery ajax. But My WebMethod is not firing.
Why?

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAdresBilgisi').click(function () {

            $.blockUI();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "OnKayitWebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: AjaxFailed

            });
            $.unblockUI();
        });

        function AjaxFailed(response) {
            if (response.d) {
                alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarısızdır.", 'Bilgi');
            }

        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            if (response.d) {
                alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarılıdır.", 'Bilgi');
            }

        }
    }); 



[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: What does your js debugger say?

Comment: I haven't used js debugger. I am using firefox "error console". But it isnt give error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this..

```
   AjaxFailed = function(response) {
        if (response.d) {
            alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarısızdır.", 'Bilgi');
        }

    }

   OnSuccess = function(response) {
        if (response.d) {
            alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarılıdır.", 'Bilgi');
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried it. It is not working. But I have tried aspx code behind web methods writing. it is working. But, I want to working with web services(asmx):)

Comment: alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarılıdır.", 'Bilgi');
can you try 
alert("Güncelleme işlemi başarılıdır., Bilgi");